# Why won't iTunes copy my new mp3 to the iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ios

I have a new mp3 in iTunes, and despite how many times I sync it with my iPod, the new song will not be copied. I tried to remove all songs from that artist, and add again, but the new song is still not on the iPod.

There is no message or indication of an error.

Any idea what's wrong here? (using a fourth-gen iPod touch and iTunes 10)

Comment: To clarify, the song will play in iTunes, and other songs will add to the iPod, but this one won't?

Comment: @Daniel Yes. It's the first time I add a new song to iTunes and it doesn't copy it to the iPod.

Comment: Is your iPod setup to auto sync all music or do you manually select?

Comment: @iampearce I manually select the artists. And I added a new song from a selected artist. I tried to remove the artist and add again, but the new song will not sync.

Comment: If you're manually syncing, grab the file from in iTunes and drag it onto the iPod itself. This will force it to copy over, and you'll be able to see it happen in the progress bar.

Comment: @iampearce it worked! Hope that don't happen with every new song I add from now...

Comment: @iampearce please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @iampearce answered in the comments:

> If you're manually syncing, grab the file from in iTunes and drag it
>   onto the iPod itself. This will force it to copy over, and you'll be
>   able to see it happen in the progress bar.