# How to sync new songs from a new laptop using iTunes v11.04?

Tags: itunes, backup, data-synchronization, windows, ipod-nano

I had an older laptop (Windows 7) with which i used to synchronize my songs on to iPod Nano using the iTunes v10.0. But recently I have shifted to a newer laptop with (Windows8.1)

I have the setting as manually manage music.(i.e. I press `CRTL + O` and add songs to the playlist and then synchronize) I got the older songs in the playlist as usual but unable to get new songs to play which I had synced.

So could anyone please tell me how to synchronize new songs keeping the old songs in the playlist intact ?

[image: Synchronize pop up window alerting you that if you synchronize then it itunes will replace the existing iTunes library with the present one]

I have tried this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35318/why-wont-itunes-copy-my-new-mp3) but could not follow "grab the file from in iTunes and drag it onto the iPod itself".

**Update**--

As i would be losing all the songs in the playlist if i synchronize new iTunes library to the playlist,(the old songs need to be present on the laptop to be able to synchronize but as it's not there then iTunes will replace the existing library with the new iTunes library) can i export the playlist from my iPod shuffle to the Windows(i.e. like a back up of the songs).

If i would be able to do this then i can easily restore the backup and also synchronize new songs to the shuffle